# How can I change a filter icon status only on the selected item of a list of items in my Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I am working on an Angular application and I have the following problem. Into a component view I have something like this:

[image]

It shown a people list, as you can see next to each person there is a little funnel icon used to filter the output of another component using the selected person (this filter behavior works fine). Once that the funnel icon related to a specific person is clicked it change color to indicate that the filter is active on the specific person.

The problem is that clicking on the funnel icon related a specific person in my list, all the funnel icons of all the persons change color, in this way:

[image]

I was handling it in this way into my component view:

```
<p-orderList [value]="people" [listStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" header="People"
filter="filter" filterBy="name" filterPlaceholder="Filter by name" dragdrop="true">
<ng-template let-person pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix fc-event" style="background-color: transparent; color:black !important;border: 0px !important;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <img src="assets/img/people/person-icon.png" style="display:inline-block;float: left; margin:2px 20px 2px 2px" width="48">
            <div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{person.name}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="people-operations-icons">

              <button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter(person, $event)">
                <svg *ngIf="isFilterByPersonActive == false" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2h-11z"/>
                </svg>

                <svg *ngIf="isFilterByPersonActive == true" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2z"/>
                </svg>


              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see to choose the empty or the full funnel icon I am doing:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter(person, $event)">
    <svg *ngIf="isFilterByPersonActive == false" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2zm1 .5v1.308l4.372 4.858A.5.5 0 0 1 7 8.5v5.306l2-.666V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .128-.334L13.5 3.308V2h-11z"/>
    </svg>

    <svg *ngIf="isFilterByPersonActive == true" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

So I am using this **isFilterByPersonActive** variable defined in my typescript code. This variable is false by default and when the user click the funnel it change status and become true.

The problem is that in this way it works on all the member of my list and not only on the selected one. How can I activate this behavior only on the selected item?

Comment: can you create a public stackblitz example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component for single persona item and use it for rendering personas items in list. All of your items will have their personal state which u can mutate with its own value/data